# POST is not getting correctly parsed into $_POST

Tags: php, post

I have a form, and it outputs this into POST:

```
<?php print file_get_contents('php://input'); ?>
```

%2Ffaults%2Ffault%5B1%5D%2F%40signal=gnc.gnc_in.ttag_sec&%2Ffaults%2Ffault%5B1%5D=increment&%2Ffaults%2Ffault%5B1%5D%2Fboolean%2F%40value=false&%2Ffaults%2Ffault%5B1%5D%2Fincrement%2F%40value=6677&%2Ffaults%2Ffault%5B1%5D%2Fthreshold%2F%40condition=&%2Ffaults%2Ffault%5B1%5D%2Fthreshold%2F%40value=&%2Ffaults%2Ffault%5B1%5D%2Ftimestamp%2F%40value=

Once urldecoded:

```
/faults/fault[1]/@signal=gnc.gnc_in.ttag_sec
/faults/fault[1]=increment
/faults/fault[1]/boolean/@value=false
/faults/fault[1]/increment/@value=6677
/faults/fault[1]/threshold/@condition=
/faults/fault[1]/threshold/@value=
/faults/fault[1]/timestamp/@value=
```

however, when I look in $_POST, what I get is:

```
   <?php print_r($_POST); ?>
Array ( [/faults/fault] => Array ( [1] => ) )
```

As you can see, a fair bit is missing from that array. Any ideas why?

Thanks.

Comment: This is because that is not form data being posted.

Comment: It is form data. I entered it into a form and hit submit. Why would it not be form data?

Answer (score 1):

You have to either restructure the form to something like:

```
<input name="xpath_expre[]" type="text" value="/faults/fault[1]/@signal" />
<input name="xpath_resul[]" type="text" value="gnc.gnc_in.ttag_sec" />
```

Or you have to parse the data yourself.

[This is the code](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/tags/php_5_3_3/main/php_variables.c?revision=301440&view=markup#l60) that's failing on how by trying to build an array when it fins `[`. As you can see, there are other points of failure on your current approach (these are comments in the code):

> - ignore leading spaces in the variable name
> - ensure that we don't have spaces or dots in the variable name
> - PHP variables cannot contain '[' in their names, so we replace the character with a '_'
> - ...

Comment: Thanks! It shouldn't be too hard to parse it myself, I just have to do explode with & and =.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is choking on the `[1]` in the variable name, which it seems to be interpreting as an array element.

I don't think these are valid field names in HTML anyway?

Depending on what you want to do, I would get rid of the `[1]` or put it to the end of each variable name, which should result in a number of arrays whose first element contains the desired value.

Something like this

```
faults/fault[1]/@signal=gnc.gnc_in.ttag_sec<br>
/faults/fault[1]=increment&/faults/fault[1]/boolean/@value=false<br>
/faults/fault/increment/@value[1]=6677<br>
/faults/fault/threshold/@condition[1]=<br>
/faults/fault/threshold/@value[1]=<br>
/faults/fault/timestamp/@value[1]/=<br>
```

Comment: They are valid field names (not ids, but names are fine), and treating form controls with `[foo]` in the name is normal PHP form parsing behaviour.

Comment: Not only normal, but useful with, for example, `<select multiple>`. (I don't say it wouldn't be useful to be able to switch this off...)

Comment: An astute observer might notice that these names are in fact XPaths ;)

It works on another page that has [some#] in the name. I'm not sure why it chokes on this page. Is there some reason PHP would choke on this input when parsing it into $_POST?

Answer (score 0):

sometimes PHP needs from us :)

```
<?php
#$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input = urldecode( '%2Ffaults%2Ffault%5B1%5D%2F%40signal=gnc.gnc_in.ttag_sec&%2Ffaults%2Ffault%5B1%5D=increment&%2Ffaults%2Ffault%5B1%5D%2Fboolean%2F%40value=false&%2Ffaults%2Ffault%5B1%5D%2Fincrement%2F%40value=6677&%2Ffaults%2Ffault%5B1%5D%2Fthreshold%2F%40condition=&%2Ffaults%2Ffault%5B1%5D%2Fthreshold%2F%40value=&%2Ffaults%2Ffault%5B1%5D%2Ftimestamp%2F%40value=' );

$_POST = array();

foreach( explode( '&', $input ) as $entry ) {
    list( $key, $value )  = explode( '=', $entry );

    $_POST[ $key ] = $value;
}

echo $input, PHP_EOL;
print_r( $_POST );
```